# Python on TensorFlow 2.13.0: Too many loss metrics leads to Out-of-Memory (OOM) Resource Exhausted Error on AWS EC2 g5.4xlarge with 24 GB memory. Why?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running Python code on a Jupyter server on an AWS EC2 instance of type `g5.4xlarge` with 24 GB of GPU memory and a Linux Amazon Machine Image (AMI). I only have 1 Jupyter notebook kernel. I am using Tensorflow version `2.13.0`.  My dataset shape right now is tiny: (43615, 28). I've checked and found that this dataset occupies the following amount of space:

```
If the cause is memory fragmentation maybe the environment variable 'TF_GPU_ALLOCATOR=cuda_malloc_async' will improve the situation. 
Current allocation summary follows.
Current allocation summary follows.
2023-10-02 12:00:44.390701: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1039] BFCAllocator dump for GPU_0_bfc
2023-10-02 12:00:44.390717: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (256):    Total Chunks: 89, Chunks in use: 82. 22.2KiB allocated for chunks. 20.5KiB in use in bin. 612B client-requested in use in bin.
2023-10-02 12:00:44.390729: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (512):    Total Chunks: 15, Chunks in use: 13. 8.0KiB allocated for chunks. 6.5KiB in use in bin. 5.2KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2023-10-02 12:00:44.390740: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (1024):   Total Chunks: 13, Chunks in use: 8. 20.0KiB allocated for chunks. 13.5KiB in use in bin. 11.9KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2023-10-02 12:00:44.390751: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (2048):   Total Chunks: 6, Chunks in use: 3. 14.5KiB allocated for chunks. 6.2KiB in use in bin. 4.7KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2023-10-02 12:00:44.390761: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (4096):   Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 0. 5.2KiB allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2023-10-02 12:00:44.390770: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (8192):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2023-10-02 12:00:44.390779: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (16384):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2023-10-02 12:00:44.390791: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (32768):  Total Chunks: 10, Chunks in use: 7. 429.2KiB allocated for chunks. 280.2KiB in use in bin. 274.0KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2023-10-02 12:00:44.390800: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (65536):  Total Chunks: 2, Chunks in use: 0. 188.0KiB allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2023-10-02 12:00:44.390810: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (131072):     Total Chunks: 8, Chunks in use: 8. 1.22MiB allocated for chunks. 1.22MiB in use in bin. 1.21MiB client-requested in use in bin.
2023-10-02 12:00:44.390820: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (262144):     Total Chunks: 2, Chunks in use: 0. 835.0KiB allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2023-10-02 12:00:44.390829: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (524288):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2023-10-02 12:00:44.390838: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (1048576):    Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 0. 1.40MiB allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2023-10-02 12:00:44.390847: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (2097152):    Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2023-10-02 12:00:44.390856: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (4194304):    Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2023-10-02 12:00:44.390866: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (8388608):    Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 1. 9.58MiB allocated for chunks. 9.58MiB in use in bin. 9.58MiB client-requested in use in bin.
2023-10-02 12:00:44.390875: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (16777216):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2023-10-02 12:00:44.390884: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (33554432):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2023-10-02 12:00:44.390895: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (67108864):   Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 1. 86.20MiB allocated for chunks. 86.20MiB in use in bin. 86.20MiB client-requested in use in bin.
2023-10-02 12:00:44.390907: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (134217728):  Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 0. 252.57MiB allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2023-10-02 12:00:44.390917: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (268435456):  Total Chunks: 5, Chunks in use: 3. 19.76GiB allocated for chunks. 12.90GiB in use in bin. 12.90GiB client-requested in use in bin.
2023-10-02 12:00:44.390927: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1062] Bin for 5.73GiB was 256.00MiB, Chunk State: 
2023-10-02 12:00:44.390943: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1068]   Size: 1.26GiB | Requested Size: 128B | in_use: 0 | bin_num: 20, prev:   Size: 512B | Requested Size: 400B | in_use: 1 | bin_num: -1, next:   Size: 86.20MiB | Requested Size: 86.20MiB | in_use: 1 | bin_num: -1
2023-10-02 12:00:44.390954: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1068]   Size: 5.61GiB | Requested Size: 128B | in_use: 0 | bin_num: 20, prev:   Size: 1.43GiB | Requested Size: 1.43GiB | in_use: 1 | bin_num: -1
2023-10-02 12:00:44.390962: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1075] Next region of size 21591359488
2023-10-02 12:00:44.390971: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7f8610000000 of size 256 next 1
2023-10-02 12:00:44.390979: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7f8610000100 of size 1280 next 2
2023-10-02 12:00:44.390988: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7f8610000600 of size 256 next 3
2023-10-02 12:00:44.390995: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7f8610000700 of size 256 next 4
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391002: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7f8610000800 of size 256 next 6
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391009: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7f8610000900 of size 256 next 7
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391017: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7f8610000a00 of size 256 next 11
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391024: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7f8610000b00 of size 256 next 20
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391031: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7f8610000c00 of size 256 next 5
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391038: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7f8610000d00 of size 256 next 12
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391045: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7f8610000e00 of size 256 next 22
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391052: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7f8610000f00 of size 256 next 21
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391059: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7f8610001000 of size 256 next 58
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391066: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] Free  at 7f8610001100 of size 256 next 63
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391073: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7f8610001200 of size 256 next 64
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391080: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7f8610001300 of size 256 next 43
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391087: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7f8610001400 of size 256 next 83
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391094: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] Free  at 7f8610001500 of size 2560 next 75
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391101: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7f8610001f00 of size 256 next 93
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391108: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7f8610002000 of size 256 next 56
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391115: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] Free  at 7f8610002100 of size 2816 next 116
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391122: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7f8610002c00 of size 256 next 81
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391151: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7f8610002d00 of size 256 next 61
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391159: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] Free  at 7f8610002e00 of size 5376 next 152
...
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391768: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7f87e580a600 of size 6156285696 next 651
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391772: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7f8954721d00 of size 1539071488 next 343
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391776: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] Free  at 7f89b02e7b00 of size 6019056896 next 18446744073709551615
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391780: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1100]      Summary of in-use Chunks by size: 
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391786: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 82 Chunks of size 256 totalling 20.5KiB
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391790: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 13 Chunks of size 512 totalling 6.5KiB
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391795: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 1 Chunks of size 1280 totalling 1.2KiB
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391799: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 7 Chunks of size 1792 totalling 12.2KiB
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391803: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 2 Chunks of size 2048 totalling 4.0KiB
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391807: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 1 Chunks of size 2304 totalling 2.2KiB
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391834: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 1 Chunks of size 10043136 totalling 9.58MiB
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391838: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 1 Chunks of size 90388224 totalling 86.20MiB
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391843: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 1 Chunks of size 1539071488 totalling 1.43GiB
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391847: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 2 Chunks of size 6156285696 totalling 11.47GiB
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391852: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1107] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 13.00GiB
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391856: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1109] Total bytes in pool: 21591359488 memory_limit_: 21591359488 available bytes: 0 curr_region_allocation_bytes_: 43182718976
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391863: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1114] Stats: 
Limit:                     21591359488
InUse:                     13953686016
MaxInUse:                  20200156672
NumAllocs:                    35443686
MaxAllocSize:               6156285696
Reserved:                            0
PeakReserved:                        0
LargestFreeBlock:                    0

2023-10-02 12:00:44.391872: W tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:497] **_____******************************************************************___________________________
2023-10-02 12:00:44.391885: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1816] RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: failed to allocate memory
```

What is interesting to me is that I've found that calculating too many loss metrics causes the above error. For example, the following code works fine, but if I uncomment the commented lines, then I get the above out-of-memory (OOM) memory error. Why is this, and how can I avoid this error while also calculating all of my desired metrics?

```
scaler_price = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaler_features = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaled_price = scaler_price.fit_transform(stack_demo[['col25']])
# I put all of the features here so I can iterate on what subsets to use and see which ones perform best
scaled_features = scaler_features.fit_transform(stack_demo[[
    'col2', 'col3','col4','col5','col6','col7','col8','col9','col10','col11','col12','col13','col14',
    'col15','col16','col17','col18','col19','col20','col21','col22','col23','col24'
]])
scaled_data = np.concatenate([scaled_price, scaled_features], axis=1)

n_epochs = 1
n_batch_size = 1 # smaller batch = slower training but better generalization

def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset) - look_back - 1):
        a = dataset[i:(i + look_back), :]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])  # Target is the 'PRICE'
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)

look_back = 24
X, y = create_dataset(scaled_data, look_back)
k = 10  # number of folds
random_seed = 13  # set the random seed value
kf = KFold(n_splits=k, shuffle=True, random_state=random_seed)

train_scores = []  # list to store train scores for each fold
test_scores = []   # list to store test scores for each fold
# mae_train_scores = []    # list to store MAE scores for each fold
# mae_test_scores = []    # list to store MAE scores for each fold
# mse_train_scores = []    # list to store MSE scores for each fold
# mse_test_scores = []    # list to store MSE scores for each fold
# huber_train_scores = []  # list to store Huber Loss scores for each fold
# huber_test_scores = []  # list to store Huber Loss scores for each fold
# mase_train_scores = []   # list to store MASE scores for each fold
# mase_test_scores = []   # list to store MASE scores for each fold

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))  # Add dropout with a dropout rate of 0.2 (adjust as needed)
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='mean_squared_error')
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=n_epochs, batch_size=n_batch_size, verbose=1)

    train_predict = model.predict(X_train)
    test_predict = model.predict(X_test)
    # train_predict = scaler_price.inverse_transform(train_predict)
    # test_predict = scaler_price.inverse_transform(test_predict)
    train_score = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_train, train_predict))
    test_score = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, test_predict))
    # mae_train_score = mean_absolute_error(y_train, train_predict)
    # mae_test_score = mean_absolute_error(y_test, test_predict)
    # mse_train_score = mean_squared_error(y_train, train_predict)
    # mse_test_score = mean_squared_error(y_test, test_predict)
    # huber_train_score = Huber()(y_train, train_predict).numpy()
    # huber_test_score = Huber()(y_test, test_predict).numpy()
    # mase_train_score = mean_absolute_error(y_train[1:], train_predict[:-1]) / np.mean(np.abs(y_train[1:] - y_train[:-1]))
    # mase_test_score = mean_absolute_error(y_test[1:], test_predict[:-1]) / np.mean(np.abs(y_test[1:] - y_test[:-1]))
    # train_scores.append(train_score)
    # test_scores.append(test_score)
    # mae_train_scores.append(mae_train_score)
    # mae_test_scores.append(mae_test_score)
    # mse_train_scores.append(mse_train_score)
    # mse_test_scores.append(mse_test_score)
    # huber_train_scores.append(huber_train_score)
    # huber_test_scores.append(huber_test_score)
    # mase_train_scores.append(mase_train_score)
    # mase_test_scores.append(mase_test_score)

# calculate average scores across folds
avg_train_score = np.mean(train_scores)
avg_test_score = np.mean(test_scores)
# avg_mae_train_score = np.mean(mae_train_scores)
# avg_mae_test_score = np.mean(mae_train_scores)
# avg_mse_train_score = np.mean(mse_train_scores)
# avg_mse_test_score = np.mean(mse_test_scores)
# avg_huber_train_score = np.mean(huber_train_score)
# avg_huber_test_score = np.mean(huber_test_scores)
# avg_mase_train_score = np.mean(mase_train_scores)
# avg_mase_test_score = np.mean(mase_test_scores)

print(f'Average Train Score: {avg_train_score:.2f} RMSE')
print(f'Average Test Score: {avg_test_score:.2f} RMSE')
# print(f'Average MAE Train Score: {avg_mae_train_score:.2f} MAE')
# print(f'Average MAE Test Score: {avg_mae_test_score:.2f} MAE')
# print(f'Average MSE Train Score: {avg_mse_train_score:.2f} MSE')
# print(f'Average MSE Test Score: {avg_mse_test_score:.2f} MSE')
# print(f'Average Huber Loss Train Score: {avg_huber_train_score:.2f} Huber')
# print(f'Average Huber Loss Test Score: {avg_huber_test_score:.2f} Huber')
# print(f'Average MASE Train Score: {avg_mase_train_score:.2f} MASE')
# print(f'Average MASE Test Score: {avg_mase_test_score:.2f} MASE')
```